# Model - View - Controller in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qitemdelegate

I understand more or less how does MPV works.
But I don't get what classes:

- `QAbstractItemModel`
- `QAbstractItemView`
- `QAbstractItemDelegate` / `QItemDelegate`

Can do for me?

If that is relevant, I'm using
`QGraphicsScene` / `QGraphicsView` with some elements (visual representation of game board) that user can interact with while the interaction logic (game rules) are encapsulated in other class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### **AbstractItemModel QAbstractItemView QAbstractItemDelegate**

Are from the ["Mode/View framework"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html)
This is a very powerful framework for the data part of your application, [here](http://www.ics.com/learning/icsnetwork/) is a presentation of the framework.

**QAbstractItemModel**

Is the base class for the **model of the MVC**.  Has a global interface for accessing and altering the data and takes care of the Observable part.

**QAbstractItemView**

Is the base class for the **view of the MVC**.  Has aglobal interface for the view/selections part and it takes care of the Observer part.  You don't have to worry about the observer pattern, the framework does it for you.

**QAbstractItemDelegate**

Is the base class for the **controller of the MVC**. 
Is the Strategy pattern for painting, editing the elements, ...

---

### **QGraphicsScene / QGraphicsView**

Are from the ["The Graphics View Framework"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html) and is **independent of the Model/View framework.**

This is also a very powerful framework for the graphics part.

> **The Scene**
>
> QGraphicsScene provides the Graphics
>   View scene. The scene has the
>   following responsibilities:
>
> Providing a fast interface for
>   managing a large number of items
>   Propagating events to each item
>   Managing item state, such as selection
>   and focus handling Providing
>   untransformed rendering functionality;
>   mainly for printing
>
> **The View**
>
> QGraphicsView provides the view
>   widget, which visualizes the contents
>   of a scene. You can attach several
>   views to the same scene, to provide
>   several viewports into the same data
>   set

---

If you want a Model to be visible in a QGraphicsView than you will have to write your own view based on the QAbstractItemView.
Take a QGraphicsView as view port widget `QAbstractScrollArea::setViewport(QWidget * widget))`  and then you can

- **add**      `QAbstractItemView::rowsInserted`,
- **remove**     `QAbstractItemView::rowsAboutToBeRemoved`
- and **change**    `QAbstractItemView::dataChanged`

the items in the scene.  Don't forget to take care of the reset an layout change events.

Comment: QAbstractItemModel provides actualy a facade for adapting a model to the interface required by the view, and doesn't necessary represent the model itself.

Comment: The concrete model can be a real model (QStandarditemModel), proxy (QSortFilterProxyModel) or it can be a facade (QSqlTableModel)